# Excel not updating independent files if not having access to the master file

Tags: excel, sharepoint, reference

I have a problem in Excel here is the explanation below:
I'm doing plans for my team to work on a project with the schedule etc...

I have one file that will be called master with every employee schedule and employee don't have access to this file and I don't want them to have access to the file.
I also created folders for each employee and each employee have access only to their folder.

The problem is that the excel present in each employee folders will not be updated in real time unless they have access to the "master" file. They only have access to their folder in read-only so they can't edit the plan.
We are using sharepoint, and for some other file with the same structure for other projects sometime it works only when I open it in the desktop app, else it won't refresh the data, and even if I open the desktop app, it will not be updated in the web version.

Note that sometime we receive a notification telling "Security warning External data connections have been disabled" and the link to the master file is shown as blocked.
If I able the connexion the workbook is in status "Unable to get to file" and the notification shows "Unable to refresh We couldn't get updated values from a linked workbook"

Also for the information my master file doesn't contain vba used for the file for the employees.

Thanks in advance for your help

We tried to give access to the master file and seemed to work in certain cases.
In data / queries & connections nothing is showing, no tab nothing , I guess it's company protection.

Also I get a notification from Trust Center and I think that might be the issue, but is there a way to reference my master file as safe ?
Or is it just a matter of reference and access to the worksheet?

The employees also tried to use the "refresh all" function in "data" tab and is not working.

Comment: So, in short you want their personal file to get information from a file they don't have access to? Then either give them access or they don't get the info...

Comment: Not exactly I want them to have access only to their own information so only their file and not to the master since it contains info of the other people as well.